# UIView with landscape only is turning to portrait

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ipad, orientation, storyboard

So I have My app running the master-detail project for iPad.

I added a `UIBarButtonItem` the show push a view "About App" to the detail.

When I push a third view to the detail (from the `UITable`) and hit the back button, it goes back to the second view on the stack of the navigationControl and the view turn to portrait!

All my viewControllers have the following code:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
        return UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(interfaceOrientation);
    else
        return UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(interfaceOrientation);
}
```

This is the error that appears:

> The view controller  returned NO
>   from -shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: for all interface
>   orientations. It should support at least one orientation.

I also tried to set Landscape on the `UIView` orientation directly from the Storyboard but doesn't work either.

Any leads?

Comment: After a few tests with other issues I realized that my About view class on storyboard was not pointing to my AboutViewController.m class. Sorry about the stupid question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a while I realised that my third view had a slightly different code.

I just copied the code form the other views and pasted on the third and it's working now...

Answer (score 0):

I would try removing the if statements to further inspect the cause of the problem and leaving only the isLandscape check in.